# Resizing makes the window's content become thinner on each loop

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glu

I was trying to fix an issue where the window stretched out the content, and I finished fixing that. But after trying it out, it works halfway through only.

Here are some images and below is the explanation of the problem:

**Image A: (when the app starts)**

[image: Original window (after starting up the app)]

**Image B: (after resizing once in any direction)**

[image: The window when resized once in any direction]

When I start the application, it is like **Image A**, a square startup window as expected, without stretching.

Then, if I resize the window in any direction, it begins to stretch more and more each time I resize, as **Image B** shows.

The resize function runs each time the window is resized thanks to this line in the main function:

```
glutReshapeFunc(resizeCallback);
```

Here's the function's code, which I'd assume is causing this:

```
void resizeCallback(int w, int h) {
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );

const GLfloat aspectRatio = (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h;
gluOrtho2D(-aspectRatio, aspectRatio, -1.0f, 1.0f);

glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
}
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone helped.
It's been a year since I last used OpenGL in C++ and I never got around fixing stretched content issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gluOrtho2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml) not only sets the projection matrix, but defines an orthographic projection matrix and multiplies the current matrix by the new matrix. You need to load the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) with [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) before `gluOrtho2D`:

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
const GLfloat aspectRatio = (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h;
gluOrtho2D(-aspectRatio, aspectRatio, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```